# Typescript - Argument of type '{ see below }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ts(2345)

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I am very new to typescript but I'm trying to force myself into using it moving forward. I have this groupBy function.

I have one last error after a day of converting this function to typescript (someone pls explain to me why this is worth it /lh) =>

Argument of type '{ temp: number; humidity: number; wind: number; clouds: number; } | { description: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
Type '{ temp: number; humidity: number; wind: number; clouds: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)

It's referring to the line, specifically to rest:
`acc[prop]?.push(rest);`

```
type ForecastData = {
  date: string;
  temp: number;
  humidity: number;
  wind: number;
  clouds: number;
};

type DescriptionData = {
  date: string;
  description: string;
};

type Group = {
  [key: string]: [] | undefined;
};
/* 
-dynamic function generator: returns a function that groups data based on the property (key) called in initial argument. 
-meant to be stored in a variable that will call this new function and take in arrays  
*/
export function groupBy(key: keyof ForecastData & keyof DescriptionData) {
  /* 
  returned dynamic function that accepts arrays as argument
  */
  return function group(arr: []) {
    return arr.reduce((acc: Group, currObj: ForecastData | DescriptionData) => {
      // create variable storing the value of the key of interest
      const prop = currObj[key];

      // destructure the rest of values into an array, extracting the date out since we don't need it anymore
      // date should be key no? but typescript isnt making it easy
      const { date, ...rest } = currObj;

      //we check if it already contains an entry for that grouping criteria or start an empty array literal for it
      acc[prop] = acc[prop] || [];

      //finall we push into this newly created/existing property's value all the remaining properties stored inside the rest variable
      acc[prop]?.push(rest); 

/*^Argument of type '{ temp: number; humidity: number; wind: number; clouds: number; } | { description: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
  Type '{ temp: number; humidity: number; wind: number; clouds: number; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)*/
 
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
}
```

What does this mean and how do I fix it? Much appreciation!

Comment: Why are you using the zero-element [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) `[]` in your code?  Such an array type cannot have any elements in it.  That's surely not what you intend. What *do* you intend?  What types should the array elements be?